# При нажатии на кнопку текст не появляется

Tags: javascript

Нужно чтобы при нажатии на кнопку появлялся текст с ответом. Переходил из состояния 'none' в 'block'.

```js
 const showAnswerBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".questions-answers__btn")

showAnswerBtn.forEach((element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
    element.classList.toggle("questions-answers__btn--active")
  });
}))

showAnswerBtn.forEach((element => {
  element.addEventListener("click", () => {
  element.parentNode.querySelector('.answer__text').classList.toggle("active")
  });  
}))
```

```css
   .answer__text {
      display: none;
    }
  
  .answer__text.active {
      display: block;
    }
```

```html
 <div>
   <div class="question-block">
     <p class="question__text"></p>
     <button class="questions-answers__btn"></button>
   </div>
   <p class="answer__text"></p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const showAnswerBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".questions-answers__btn")

showAnswerBtn.forEach((element => {
    element.addEventListener("click", () => {
        element.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.answer__text').classList.toggle("active")
    });
}))
```

```css
.answer__text {
  display: none;
}

.answer__text.active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="question-block">
    <p class="question__text"></p>
    <button class="questions-answers__btn">тык</button>
  </div>
  <p class="answer__text">Ответ</p>
</div>
```